# using facebook-C#-sdk, I login but then I cant validate the session

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I donwloaded FacebookSDK_V5.0.1_BETA. I configured everything to work on localhost. I ran the sample Mvcwebsite. It seems to work fine as I can login without problem, but when I want to visit the "about" I get redirected to the index. It looks like the facebook cookie generated by the js SDK is not getting to the server.

to see if I had a valid session, I added the following to the Index.asp view

and it showed my profile pic.

What am I doing wrong? I tried with the webforms sample and got the same resutl.

Comment: are you running the sample in IIS? if not you can you try running on IIS.

Comment: That was it! thank you very much. I was running it on the  Development Server, but when i tried in IIS it ran well. Is there a way to make it wokr on the ASP.NET Development Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the application in IIS. There are some issues with Facebook's javascript SDK and cookies when developing with VS Dev Server.

Comment: thak's a lot. I'm publishing my site in IIS, then I attach the w3wp.exe to debug. This is the best I could do